# How to change class name when click in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to change class name of "product fav" to "product fav active" to class when click on. It should be conditional if the class in active then it needs to be deleted.

Comment: show some code...So that it would be clear what exactly do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<template>
  <main>
   <div class="product fav" :class="isActive ? 'active' : ''" />
    <button @click="isActive = !isActive" />
  </main>
</template>
```

So you should use `v-bind:class` . (`:class` is short-hand of it.)

Comment: in npm I got this error "Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Comment: You should wrap your elements with one root element like: 
`<template>
<button><div></div>
</template>`

Comment: I did but it has same error

Comment: Can you try like this? (I eddited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could manage boolean `isActive`, class depends on.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="test-template">
    <div :class="{'active':isActive}" @click="toggleClassActive">Test toggle class Active</div>
</script>
```

**Vue:**

```js
var vueInstance = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#test-template',
    data: {            
      isActive: false
    },
    mounted: function () {},
    computed: {},
    methods: {
        toggleClassActive () {        
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      }
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willystyle/7aot5zd0/27/)